How To Include Condition In Where Clause Based On Another Column Value
I have the following Query:
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Customers
WHERE ActiveFlag='Y'

But I only want to Apply the WHERE clause if another field called ManagedBy is not null and not empty. So I want to do something like this:
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Customers

-- something like this:
    IF (ManagedBy is not null AND ManagedBy <> '') Then
       WHERE ActiveFlag = 'Y'
    END

How would I write this in SQL?

where managedBy is not null and managedBy <> '' and activeFlag = 'Y'?? Is that what you want?

@Isolated Well, I only want the Where ActiveFlag='Y' to be included if ManagedBy is not null and ManagedBy <> ''.  Otherwise I don't want anything in the Where Clause.

Have you considered the OR operator?

Is ActiveFlag nullable? Or constrained to 'Y' and 'N' only?

char(1) Not Nullable

Just use OR boolean conditions
WHERE (ManagedBy IS NULL OR ManagedBy = '' OR ActiveFlag = 'Y')


Thanks! This returns the same results and even easier to understand and ran much faster.

SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Customers
WHERE ActiveFlag =
 CASE
   WHEN ManagedBy is not null AND ManagedBy <> '' THEN 'Y'
   ELSE ActiveFlag 
 END =ActiveFlag 

Could you please try this one

This'll work but it's not SARGable. What's wrong with a good ol' OR?

I guess, it would be better if you provided some sample code. For me it is unclear if author wants WHERE (ManagedBy is not null AND ManagedBy <> '') OR ActiveFlag = 'Y'  or my query

I updated the question a little.  If ManagedBy exists, then apply the WHERE clause - Where ActiveFlag = 'Y'.   Otherwise don't apply it at all.

Could just coalesce ManagedBy into an empty string and check if the value is empty.
SELECT 
     FirstName
    ,LastName
FROM Customers
WHERE COALESCE(ManagedBy,'') = '' 
  OR (COALESCE(ManagedBy,'') <> '' AND ActiveFlag = 'Y' )


I missed that part of the requirement. Updating my answer to account for that.

This is what you want:
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Customers
WHERE (COALESCE(ManagedBy,'') <> '' AND ActiveFlag='Y') 
OR COALESCE(ManagedBy,'') = ''


This doesn't capture empty string ('') correctly. If ManagedBy = '' it should be handled as if it were NULL.

This answer is giving me the exact result I was looking for. Thanks.

A + ~AB simplifies to A + B in boolean logic.
